# Proving $a_n=\frac 1 2 \max\{a_{n-k},a_{n-k+1},...,a_{n-1}\}+1$ is monotone and finding its limit

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

> Let $(a_n)^{\infty}_{n=1}$ defined like so: let $2\le k\in \mathbb N$ and $a_1,a_2...a_k\in \mathbb R$, $a_j\le 2, \ j=1,2,...,k$.
>
> Let $\forall n\ge k+1 : a_n=\frac 1 2 \max\{a_{n-k},a_{n-k+1},...,a_{n-1}\}+1$
>
> 1. show that $(a_n)^{\infty}_{n=k+1}$ is monotone.
> 2. Prove that the sequence id converging and find it's limit.

1. Suppose WLOG that $a_{n-1}$ is the maximum, then we'll need to show that: $\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}\ge 1$ so take: $\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n-2}}=\frac{\frac 1 2 a_{n-1} +1}{\frac 1 2 a_{n-2}+1}=\frac{a_{n-1} +2}{a_{n-2}+2}$ and I know from the supposition that $a_{n-1}\ge a_{n-2}$ so we have: $\frac{a_{n-1} +2}{a_{n-2}+2}\ge1$
2. If I try to sketch $a_n$ I see that every element is $\le 2$, so trying to prove this by induction:

   for $n=1$ we have $a_n=\frac 1 2 \max\{a_{n-1}\}+1$ and from the given info we know that: $a_{n-1}=a_k\le 2$ so $a_n\le 2$.

   Suppose the assertion is true for $m$ and prove for $m+1$: 
   $a_{m+1}=\frac 1 2 max\{a_{m-k-1},a_{m-k},a_{m-k+1},...,a_{m-1}\}+1$ and from the induction hypothesis: $a_{m-k-1},a_{m-k},a_{m-k+1},...,a_{m-2}\le 2$ so it must be that $a_{m-1}\le 2$.

   Now if every elemt is bounded by $2$ then the sequence is bounded and monotone so it must converge and since it's monotone increasing it must converge to it's supermum which is $2$.

Comment: In part 1 you can only show the weak inequalities with $\ge$ (but you do not need the strict $>$ for part 2).

Comment: @gammatester is a constant function also considered monotone ?

Comment: Yes. Monotone is defined with $\le$ or $\ge$, **strictly** monotone with $<$ or $>$.

Comment: (1) It is wrong to say $a_{n-1}$ is the maximum due to WLOG.  This is not a WLOG situation unless you make some  really heavy (and in my opinion, nonobvious) unsaid arguments.  You can make that assumption as an *inductive* assumption though.  Be careful about your range and base case though.  (2) You have proven that an upper bound is $2$, but not that it is the least upper bound.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(1) First, we show by induction that
$$\forall\,n\geq 1,\qquad a_{n}\leq 2.\tag{1}$$
Indeed, this is the hypothesis, if $k\leq n$ and for if we have  proved that $a_n\leq 2$ for $n<m$, then
$$a_{m}= \frac{1}{2}\max(a_{m-1},\ldots,a_{m-k})+1\leq 1+1=2.$$
and the $(1)$ follows.

(2) Next, we show by that
$$\forall\,n> k,\qquad a_{n}\leq a_{n+1}.\tag{2}$$
Indeed,
$$a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}\max(a_{n},\ldots,a_{n-k+1})+1
\geq \frac{a_n}{2}+1\geq \frac{a_n}{2}+\frac{a_n}{2}=a_n.$$
and the sequence is increasing.

(3) Note that, for $n\geq k$,
$$2-a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}\min(2-a_n,2-a_{n-1},\ldots,2-a_{n-k+1})\leq \frac{1}{2}(2-a_n)$$
hence
$$\forall\,n\geq k,\qquad 0\leq 2-a_n\leq \frac{1}{2^{n-k}}(2-a_k).$$
So, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=2$.

Comment: Nice answer, small typo, (2) should be $\forall n > k$

Comment: How did you prove (1) ?, for (2) how do you justify this $...\color{red}{\geq} \frac{a_n}{2}+1\geq \frac{a_n}{2}+\frac{a_n}{2}$ ?

Comment: Because he proved that $a_n \le 2$, the can say $1 \ge {a_n \over 2}$.  The $\max(...) \ge a_n$ following from the fact that the sequence is increasing, so $a_n$ is largest value in the max.  It only holds for $n > 1$ though, and the reason only holds for $n > 2k$

Comment: @DanielV how did he prove (1) ? Is it essentially like you did only without all the steps ? (Sorry for all the questions and thanks for the help).

Comment: @GinKin No his proof is a bit better organized than mine.  You ask what is the value of $\frac 12 \max(2, 2, 2, ...) + 1$, and see that the largest value it can make is $2$.  So as long as none of the initial $A_{1..k}$ are more than $2$, none of the rest will be either.

Answer (score 2):

***(1) Monotone***

If you want to use induction, for $i > 2k$, you have to prove 2 things with induction:
$$(\forall a \in A)\, 0 < a < 2 \tag{a}$$
$$(\forall i \in \mathbb{N})\, A_i > A_{i-1} \tag{b}$$

Try proving either by itself and you'll see they are codependent (each implies the other), so these have to be proven simultaneously.

$$A_i = {1 \over 2} \max\{\underbrace{A_{i-1}}_x , \underbrace{A_{i-2}, A_{i-3}, \dots }_Y\} + 1$$

Inductive assumption **(b)** allow you to infer that $(\forall y \in Y)\, x > y$ (by strong inductive assumption) and thus $$\max\{A_{i-1}, A_{i-2}, A_{i-3}, \dots \} = A_{i-1} \tag{c}$$

Inductive assumption **(a)** is that $0 < A_{i-1} < 2$ and by **(c)** you get that $0 < A_i < 2$ and $A_{i-1} < A_i$.

If you wish to be pedantic for the $i \le 2k$, I think the easiest way is just to consider a sequence $$B_i = \begin{cases} A_i &\text{ for } i > k \\ \text{sorted}(A_{1 \cdots k})_i &\text{ for } i \le k\end{cases}$$ and the same argument as above holds.

***(2) Steady state***

**(c)** allows us to infer that for $i > 2k$, $A_i = {1 \over 2} \max\{A_{i-1}, \dots\} + 1 = {1 \over 2} A_{i - 1} + 1$.  Steady state assumption (because we know it's not periodic) is that $A_{\infty} = A_{\infty - 1}$, so
$$A_{\infty} = {1 \over 2} A_{\infty - 1} + 1$$
$$A_{\infty} = {1 \over 2} A_{\infty} + 1$$
$$A_{\infty} = 2$$

The problem with the approach in the question is that $A_i < L$ and $A$ being monotone isn't enough to assume that $A$ increases to $L$.  You can just as well prove $A_i < \text{anything larger than 2}$.  That is why I recommend steady state, but there may be other valid approaches someone else could suggest.

Comment: Why for $i > 2k$ ?

Comment: @GinKin Because the initial $k$ items can be in any order, the second set of $k$ can't assume that the previous $k$ are in order, which is the inductive assumption.  Only after $2k$ can you assume inductively that the previous $k$ are in order.  You can change this assumption to $i>0$ by considering the sequence $B$ instead.

Comment: I still don't understand what guarantees that from the $2k+1$ element onward they would be ordered ? And why does the order matter in a set ? because we want to show that it's monotone ? Can't we assume $k$ elements are ordered by the Axiom of Choice ?

Comment: Sorry I shouldn't say ordered, I should say increasing, it's a programming habit to say "in order".  You know that the first $k$ elements aren't increasing.  So at what point can you assume that the previous $k$ elements are increasing?

Comment: Okay, still, why does it have to be more than an even number ? Suppose that $a_k$ are 0.9, 1.21, 0.2, 1.3, 0.4,... (alternating between larger and smaller than 1).

Comment: It only has to be large enough to be true.  If you find that to be troublesome, then just change all the $A_n$ to $B_n$ and then you can inductively prove the sequence $B_n$ is always increasing, rather than after a certain point.